# How do you convert an etree Element (not ElementTree) to a string for printing?

Tags: python, elementtree

Clearly, xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring() works for converting an ElementTree to a string, but I see no corresponding method for Element. Am I missing something?

Comment: What should the result look like? In particular, how do you want to handle the `.tail` data?

Comment: I simply want a string representation of only the xml content, for printing/logging purposes. From the string I can pretty print or whatever. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: What does "only the XML content" mean? Show a clear example, and make sure you understand how etree organizes its parsed element tree data, especially how it handles text that's outside the tags.

Comment: The result should be identical to what is returned for ElementTree.tostring(). I am looking for something like Element.tostring() but that does not seem to exist.

Comment: Let's make a concrete example. I have an XML fragment like `<foo>bar</foo>baz`. Should the result of this stringification look exactly like that? Should it include the `baz` or not?

Comment: Sorry, I was not considering malformed xml. Not sure. I don't really care about that edge case. Whatever ElementTree.tostring() does is fine.

Comment: That isn't malformed, as long as that fragment is inside another tag: `<container><foo>bar</foo>baz</container>`. That's why it's called eXtensible *Markup* Language, not "extensible tree description language" or something. Etree considers the `baz` text to be part of the `foo` Element, as its `.tail`.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This looks like a misunderstanding. Instead of an `Element.tostring()` method, there is the `xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring()` function which takes an `Element` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
from lxml import etree
from xml.etree import *

xmltemp = """<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
 <package>
  <primary>Care Physician</primary>
  <officeName>Tower Radiology</officeName>
</package>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xmltemp).getroottree()

with open('towRadFile.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print = True, xml_declaration = True, encoding='UTF-8', standalone=False))
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<package>
  <primary>Care Physician</primary>
  <officeName>Tower Radiology</officeName>
</package>
```

Comment: That only works if element is an ElementTree. How do you do this if it is an Element?

Comment: Are you referring to the 'Element' class representing a single node in the tree?

Comment: Correct, Element.

Comment: Unfortunately, ```tostring()``` is not a an available object of Element class, ```text()``` is the object available. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element

Comment: See my answer above.

Comment: The only other option is to pass your node to a custom tostring function to clean up a single node found from ElementTree.iter() . Would seem the most viable option  or serialize the XML to JSON and extract that way. /sorry

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like my question was not clear. Here's the solution I found:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as eTree
string_xml = eTree.tostring(xml_element)
```

This allows for easy logging, like this:

```
def log_xml_element(xml_element):
    log.info(parseString(eTree.tostring(xml_element)).toprettyxml())
```

Comment: If the question isn't clear, then you should edit the question. This answer is not very clear either. It appears that the solution involves minidom, but that is not explained.